# Splitting a string in Python so that output has line breaks AND without " and brackets

Tags: python, string

I have an input string which is as follows:

```
input_string = [{"name":"Jason","cover":25.1},{"name":"Jake","cover":62.23},{"name":"Amy","cover":70.11}]
```

I need output string with `line breaks` and without `“` and  `brackets`

```
output_string_1 = 
name:Jason, cover:25.1
name:Jake, cover:62.23
name:Amy, cover:70.11
```

Finally, I require output string 2 which eliminates repeating terms and has a `|` separator

```
output_string_2 = 
name | cover
Jason | 25.1
Jake | 62.23
Amy | 70.11
```

`output_string_1` and `output_string_2` should be of type `str`

I would need a solution which can be done programmatically irrespective of the number of elements within the string

Comment: That looks like json... why not use json.loads?

Comment: it is not VALID json. My input that I receive is a string as described above

Comment: Your example is valid JSON: https://repl.it/repls/SlategrayStarchyChief

Comment: I have corrected my question. apologies. please check the input_string

Comment: Your edit makes it look like your `input_string` isn't actually a string but a list of dictionaries.  Is that correct?

Comment: as @AlexHall said, your input_string is valid JSON

Comment: my input is of type str

Comment: @Symphony: copy and paste the line you gave us which starts `input_string =` into a Python console, and then type `print(type(input_string))`.  Your real input may be of type string, but your last edit made what you gave us _not_ a string.

Comment: your input_string is valid JSON, @AlexHall gave you a working example of what you can do with that valid JSON string, and you should give us [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string as json to a list of dicts:

```
In [11]: lst = json.loads(input_string)

In [12]: print("name | cover")
     ...: for d in lst:
     ...:     print(d["name"], "|", d["cover"])
     ...:
name | cover
Jason | 25.1
Jake | 62.23
Amy | 70.11

# To return the string
In [13]: "\n".join(["name | cover"] + [d["name"] + " | " + str(d["cover"]) for d in lst])
Out[13]: 'name | cover\nJason | 25.1\nJake | 62.23\nAmy | 70.11'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Simple and Elegant !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with `str.join`, list comprehensions and f-strings:

```
from ast import literal_eval

L = literal_eval(input_string)

print('\n'.join([f'name:{d["name"]}, cover:{d["cover"]}' for d in L]))

name:Jason, cover:25.1
name:Jake, cover:62.23
name:Amy, cover:70.11

print('\n'.join(['name | cover'] + [f'{d["name"]} | {d["cover"]}' for d in L]))

name | cover
Jason | 25.1
Jake | 62.23
Amy | 70.11
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called ast.literal_eval(string_with_list)

You can input your string with your list and dictionaries and your output is the real list of dicts.

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = ast.literal_eval('[{"name":"Jason","cover":25.1},{"name":"Jake","cover":62.23},{"name":"Amy","cover":70.11}]')
>>> print(a)
[{'name': 'Jason', 'cover': 25.1}, {'name': 'Jake', 'cover': 62.23}, {'name': 'Amy', 'cover': 70.11}]
```

Then you can easily...

```
for y in a:
    print("name:" + y["name"] + ", cover:" + str(y["cover"]))
```

So you ready code is:

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval('[{"name":"Jason","cover":25.1},{"name":"Jake","cover":62.23},{"name":"Amy","cover":70.11}]')
for y in a:
    # [3 STRINGS]
    print("name:" + y["name"] + ", cover:" + str(y["cover"]))
output_string_1 = "name:" + a[0]["name"] + ", cover:" + str(a[0]["cover"]) + "\nname:"+ a[1]["name"] + ", cover:" + str(a[1]["cover"]) + "\nname:"+ a[2]["name"] + ", cover:" + str(a[2]["cover"]))
output_string_2 = "name | cover\n" + a[0]["name"] + " | " + str(a[0]["cover"]) + "\n"+ a[1]["name"] + " | " + str(a[1]["cover"]) + "\n"+ a[2]["name"] + " | " + str(a[2]["cover"]))
print(output_string_1)
print(output_string_2)
```

The result:

```
[3 STRINGS]
name:Jason, cover:25.1
name:Jake, cover:62.23
name:Amy, cover:70.11

[1 STRING]
name:Jason, cover:25.1
name:Jake, cover:62.23
name:Amy, cover:70.11

[1 STRING]
name | cover
Jason | 25.1
Jake | 62.23
Amy | 70.11
```

If you like my answer please vote for me!